# Input-group-btn not showing up after adding JQuery to file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is what I am doing.

- Creating a Modal that allows users to input a password
- There will be a button to the right of the password field that allows you to show/hide the text in the field.

Here is what I have so far. My example works perfect.

- http://jsfiddle.net/5wzs0njf/1/

This is my html code:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" id="passwordButton" class="btn btn-primary">Show</button>
      </span>
</div>
```

This is my query function:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$(".form-control").each(function (index, input) {
var $input = $(input);
$("#passwordButton").click(function () {
  var change = "";
  if ($(this).html() === "Show") {
    $(this).html("Hide");
    change = "text";
  } else {
    $(this).html("Show");
    change = "password";
  }
  var rep = $("<input type='" + change + "' />")
    .attr("id", $input.attr("id"))
    .attr("name", $input.attr("name"))
    .attr('class', $input.attr('class'))
    .val($input.val())
    .insertBefore($input);
  $input.remove();
  $input = rep;
}).insertAfter($input);
});
});
</script>
```

However, when I add my jquery to my file at the bottom, my button disappears. This is what it should look like (the way it looks before I add my jquery)[image: Before JQuery]

This is how it looks after.

[image: After Adding]

Is there something I am doing wrong that I am missing?  I have tried to format this into a very easy to read/understand question.

Comment: Consider setting the fiddle up so that it is broken, or be more specific about what you mean by "add my jquery to my file at the bottom."  I added it to the bottom but the button didn't disappear...

Comment: Looks css issue to me... can you provide your css here

Comment: At the bottom of my file, I add the script.  If I run it without the script in my dev environment, the button shows up.  When I add that script, it breaks it apparently.  @TonyHinkle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a functional error in your code. 
In your code

```
$("#passwordButton").click(function () {
  var change = "";
  .....
}).insertAfter($input);
```

You don't need this `insertAfter()` function because you have already changed the name of the button.
Just remove that function as

```
$("#passwordButton").click(function () {
  var change = "";
  .....
});
```

Now your code must work just fine.

Comment: I figured this out on my own but this is the correct answer.  Thank you!